# Каким простым способом сделать hr

Tags: html, css

```css
.preim {
  background-color: #292929;
  position: relative; }
  .preim__caption {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Proxima_Nova_Semibold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 488px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 50px; }
  .preim__items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 70px; }
  .preim__item {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 30px; }
  .preim__title {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Proxima_Nova";
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 0 20px; }
  .preim__disc {
    color: #e8e7e7;
    font-family: "Proxima_Nova";
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 15px;
    width: 170px; }
  .preim__icon {
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3; }
    .preim__icon img {
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #27a4ff;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto; }
    .preim__icon-block {
      background: red;
      width: 100px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2; }
  .preim__lines {
    position: absolute;
    top: 144px;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 1; }
  .preim__line {
    width: 85%;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 3px dashed #27a4ff;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0; }
  .preim__line:after {
    content: "";
    border-left: 10px solid #27a4ff;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -5px; }
    @mixin line {
    width: 85%;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 3px dashed #27a4ff;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}
@mixin lineAfter {
    content: "";
    border-left: 10px solid #27a4ff;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="preim">
  <div class="preim__lines">
    <div class="preim__line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="preim__caption">Несколько преимуществ и причин, почему выбирают именно нас:</div>
    <div class="preim__items">
      <div class="preim__item">
        <div class="preim__icon"><img src="../img/preim/adv_icon_1.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="img1"/></div>
        <div class="preim__title">Приемлемая цена</div>
        <p class="preim__disc">Компания осуществляет международные автомобильные перевозки уже более  10 лет. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="preim__item">
        <div class="preim__icon"><img src="../img/preim/adv_icon_2.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="img2"/></div>
        <div class="preim__title">Скорость работы</div>
        <p class="preim__disc">Компания осуществляет международные автомобильные перевозки уже более  10 лет.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="preim__item">
        <div class="preim__icon-block">
          <div class="preim__icon"><img src="../img/preim/adv_icon_3.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="img3"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="preim__title">Свои грузчики</div>
        <p class="preim__disc">Компания осуществляет международные автомобильные перевозки уже более  10 лет. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>.
```

Подскажите каким простым способом сделать синий hr как на картинке. Думаю про псевдоэлементы, но не удобно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос как сделать красный фон выше hr? z-index не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете в виду просто прерывистую линию со стрелкой на конце?

Comment: так вам не удобно или не умеете ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Вопрос как сделать красный фон выше hr? z-index не помогает

Comment: тогда надо делать в три слоя - первый ваша полоска - второй ваш красный блок и третий круглый

Comment: @МаксимЛенский так и сделал, z-index дал, но не срабатывает. Посмотрите, может что не верно?

Comment: или z-index применяется только к элементам с position?

Comment: Затупил, забыл ljgbcfnm position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.line{
  width:500px;
  height:0;
  border-bottom:4px dashed blue;
  margin:100px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.line:after{
  content:"";
  border-left:16px solid blue;
  border-right:0px solid transparent;
  border-top:8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left:100%; top:-6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Минус за то что не соответствует заданию, ничего личного.

Comment: @Duoxx  как это не соответствует заданию ? читать не умеете что ли ? `Подскажите каким простым способом сделать синий hr как на картинке.`

Comment: Вопрос как сделать красный фон выше hr? z-index не помогает

Comment: @Duoxx  он изменил вопрос - на момент когда я писал ответ вопрос был именно в синей полосе ..что за привычка __минусовать ? дружественный ruSO